# How to disable bottom div when absolute div on top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to stackoverflow and can't seem to find an answer to my issue - please put link to similar question if I missed it, but I have gave it a strong gander already.

I am making a portfolio site and when a user clicks a project, the clicked div slides out and the bottom div is revealed with the project case study.

The problem: When user scrolls down to project thumbs on sliding div, the lower div scrolls with it - therefore when the user clicks the project, the case study is already scrolled down. I need it to reveal with the case study at scrolltop(0)

Here is a simplified version of what I have so you can get an idea:

```js
// View Project Details (user clicks thumbnail from LP) CTA function
  $(".projThumb").click(function()
  {
   $("#nav-icon3").toggleClass('open');
   $(".projDetails").fadeIn( 500 );
   // $('.lowerContainer').css('position','absolute');
   $('.mainContentWrap').openSlide();
   
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   
   if(id == 'Proj1')
   {
    $("#Proj1_Details").fadeIn( 500 );
    
    //get persona image height so background shape is proportional
    var personaImgHeight = parseInt($("#personaImg1").height());
    $(".containImg").css("height", personaImgHeight + "px");
    $(".personaImgWrap").css("height", personaImgHeight + "px"); 

   } else if (id == 'Proj2') {
    $("#Proj2_Details").fadeIn( 500 );
    
    //get persona image height so background shape is proportional
    var personaImgHeight = parseInt($("#personaImg2").height());
    $(".containImg").css("height", personaImgHeight + "px");
    $(".personaImgWrap").css("height", personaImgHeight + "px"); 

   } else if (id == 'Proj3') {
    $("#Proj3_Details").fadeIn( 500 );
    
    //get persona image height so background shape is proportional
    var personaImgHeight = parseInt($("#personaImg3").height());
    $(".containImg").css("height", personaImgHeight + "px");
    $(".personaImgWrap").css("height", personaImgHeight + "px"); 

   } else if (id == 'Proj4') {
    $("#Proj4_Details").fadeIn( 500 );
   };

  });
```

```css
.lowerContainer
{
 width:80%;
 max-width: 2050px;
 height: auto;
 min-height:100vh;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:#f9f9f9;
 position: relative;
 /*left:10%;*/
}
.revealPanel 
{
 width: 100%;
 min-height:100vh;
 float: left;
 margin-top:0;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 padding:0;
 /*position: fixed;*/

}

.mainContent
{
 width:80%;
 max-width: 2050px;
 height:auto;
 top:0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-bottom:0;
 margin-left:auto;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll; 
 opacity: 1;
}
.mainContentWrap
{
 width:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="lowerContainer group">
 <section class="revealPanel group">

  <!--  ****************************** 
  PROJECT CASE STUDY GOES HERE  
  ******************************** -->

 </section>  <!-- /revealPanel -->
</div>  <!-- /lowerContainer -->

<div class="mainContent">
 <div class="mainContentWrap">
  <!--  ****************************** 
   MY WORK SECTION  
   ******************************** -->
   <div class="myWork group">
    <!-- Project container (Contains project thumbnails )  -->
    <div class="projContainer">

     <h3 class="secTitle">Recent Work</h3>
     <div class="projectsWrap">
      <div class="row">
       
       <!-- Project 1 -->
       <div class="projects col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <div class="projThumb" id="Proj1">
         <img src="assets/proj1.png" width="100%" alt="">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <!-- Project 2 -->
       <div class="projects col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <div class="projThumb" id="Proj2">
         <img src="assets/proj2.png" width="100%" alt="">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <!-- Project 3 -->
       <div class="projects col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <div class="projThumb" id="Proj3">
         <img src="assets/proj3.png" width="100%" alt="">
        </div>
       </div>

       <!-- Project 4 -->
       <div class="projects col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <div class="projThumb" id="Proj4">
         <img src="assets/proj4.png" width="100%" alt="">
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>  <!-- /row -->
     </div>  <!-- /projectWrap -->

    </div>  <!-- projectsWrap -->
    <!-- <div class="triBg" id="triBg-myWork"></div> -->
   
    </div>  <!-- /myWork -->
 </div>
</div>  <!-- /mainContent -->
```

Comment: The code snippet has errors and it's not running

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said you want to happen, without really looking at your massive amount of code, I think you are over complicating this.

You can make use of jQuery's `.slideToggle()` http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

You can also utilize the fact that you can have multiple elements with the same class to help minimize the amount of repeated code.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.projectButton', function(){
  $(this).siblings('.projectInfo').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.projectInfo {
  display: none;
}

.projectButton {
  height: 25px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="projectsContainer">
  
  <div class="project" id="project1">
    <div class="projectButton">Project 1</div>
    <div class="projectInfo">Project 1 information goes here</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="project" id="project2">
    <div class="projectButton">Project 2</div>
    <div class="projectInfo">Project 2 information goes here</div>    
  </div>
  
  <div class="project" id="project3">
    <div class="projectButton">Project 3</div>
    <div class="projectInfo">Project 3 information goes here</div>    
  </div>
  
  <div class="project" id="project4">
    <div class="projectButton">Project 4</div>
    <div class="projectInfo">Project 4 information goes here</div>    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I am new to this, so I am sure its heavy... but I didn't know how to post my question without posting my whole site basically.  I have 2 layers, the top is position absolute and slides over the project details page.  see example at reeseholtze.com/portfolio.

Comment: @ReeseHoltze yeah, no worries, but based on your question and quickly glancing at your code I think you are definitely over complicating things. Take a look at the solution above, I think it can work for you and help you minimize your jQuery code. Keep in mind the `this` keyword is referring to the element that has just been clicked, and then jQuery's `siblings()` function can help you find a sibling element to slide down, in this situation `.projectInfo`.

Comment: I had to write if else for each project because it wasn't getting the height of my persona images btw, it was a work around until I have time to make it lean :\

Comment: Why do you need the height?

Comment: Okay, I will try and make that work, right now I am sliding it off screen to the left...

Comment: Because they have background boxes behind them... its hard to describe, you would have to go to the link lol

Comment: You can also use `jQuery UI` and set the direction parameter of `slideToggle`

Comment: Okay, I am working on cleaning that up now... Once I do that though, do you have a recommendation on how to make sure that lower div doesn't scroll?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it's scrolling with the mouse? You can also set that divs overflow to none so no scrolling happens

Comment: did you try going to my site?   reeseholtze . c o m

Comment: you will see what I mean there :)